Estoy intentado tomar dos valores de una consulta en SQL Server para realizar la división de dos valores de una misma columna
Esta es la consulta en SQL Server en la que me regresa en formato de columnas (nombre del mes) el valor del activo circulante (código=1100000000000000) en un renglón y el valor del pasivo circulante (código=2100000000000000) en el segundo renglón. Necesito obtener en un solo renglón el ratio de la razón financiera de Liquidez (Activo Circulante/Pasivo Circulante) por cada mes para graficarlo.
SELECT ACTIVO.CODIGO_C, ACTIVO.SALDO1 AS ENERO, ACTIVO.SALDO2 AS FEBRERO, 
ACTIVO.SALDO3 AS MARZO, ACTIVO.SALDO4 AS ABRIL, ACTIVO.SALDO5 AS MAYO,
ACTIVO.SALDO6 AS JUNIO, ACTIVO.SALDO7 AS JULIO, ACTIVO.SALDO8 AS AGOSTO,
ACTIVO.SALDO9 AS SEPTIEMBRE, ACTIVO.SALDO10 AS OCTUBRE, ACTIVO.SALDO11 AS NOVIEMBRE,
ACTIVO.SALDO12 AS DICIEMBRE
FROM SALDOSCC ACTIVO

LEFT OUTER JOIN SALDOSCC PASIVO ON
(ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = PASIVO.CODIGO_C) AND
(ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = '1100000000000000') AND
(ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = '2100000000000000')

WHERE ( (ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = '1100000000000000' OR ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = '2100000000000000') AND (LTRIM(STR(ACTIVO.PERIODO,4)) = '2024') )

Este es el resultado del Query:

Resultado esperado:

Por su apoyo, gracias.

Agrega un ejemplo de salida esperada

Listo, agregue el resultado de la consulta y lo esperado, gracias.

Tienes este join
LEFT OUTER JOIN SALDOSCC PASIVO ON
(ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = PASIVO.CODIGO_C) AND
(ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = '1100000000000000') AND
(ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = '2100000000000000')

El cual te produce 2 filas, lo que dificulta cualquier operación entre la fila_1 y fila_2. Si lo cambias por
INNER JOINSALDOSCC PASIVO ON
(ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = '1100000000000000') AND
(ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = '2100000000000000')

Te producirá una sola fila con las columnas de la fila_1 + fila_2, lo cual te permitirá hacer la división que buscas.
Luego deberás rotar (pivotear) el resultado para convertir esas columnas en filas y obtener el resultado esperado. Y como estás usando SQL Server, puedes usar UNPIVOT
Algo así:
WITH Ratios AS (
select 
    ACTIVO.SALDO1  / PASIVO.SALDO1  AS ENERO,
    ACTIVO.SALDO2  / PASIVO.SALDO2  AS FEBRERO,
    ACTIVO.SALDO3  / PASIVO.SALDO3  AS MARZO,
    ACTIVO.SALDO4  / PASIVO.SALDO4  AS ABRIL,
    ACTIVO.SALDO5  / PASIVO.SALDO5  AS MAYO,
    ACTIVO.SALDO6  / PASIVO.SALDO6  AS JUNIO,
    ACTIVO.SALDO7  / PASIVO.SALDO7  AS JULIO,
    ACTIVO.SALDO8  / PASIVO.SALDO8  AS AGOSTO,
    ACTIVO.SALDO9  / PASIVO.SALDO9  AS SEPTIEMBRE,
    ACTIVO.SALDO10  / PASIVO.SALDO10  AS OCTUBRE,
    ACTIVO.SALDO11  / PASIVO.SALDO11  AS NOVIEMBRE,
    ACTIVO.SALDO12  / PASIVO.SALDO12  AS DICIEMBRE
from SALDOSCC as ACTIVO
INNER JOIN SALDOSCC as PASIVO ON ACTIVO.CODIGO_C='110000000000000000'  AND PASIVO.CODIGO_C = '210000000000000000'
WHERE ( (ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = '1100000000000000' OR ACTIVO.CODIGO_C = '2100000000000000') AND (LTRIM(STR(ACTIVO.PERIODO,4)) = '2024') )
)
SELECT Mes, Valor
FROM Ratios
UNPIVOT (
    Valor FOR Mes IN ([ENERO], [FEBRERO], [MARZO], [ABRIL], [MAYO], [JUNIO],[JULIO], [AGOSTO], [SEPTIEMBRE], [OCTUBRE], [NOVIEMBRE], [DICIEMBRE])
) AS Unpivoted;


Hola Yussef muchas gracias por tu ayuda, experimentando en base a tus respuestas, quedo resuelto.

Hola Yussef: Finalmente quedo resuelto como se muestra a continuación:
WITH RATIOS AS
(
SELECT ROUND((E.SALDO1/P.SALDO1),2) AS ENERO,
ROUND((E.SALDO2/P.SALDO2),2) AS FEBRERO,
ROUND((E.SALDO3/P.SALDO3),2) AS MARZO,
ROUND((E.SALDO4/P.SALDO4),2) AS ABRIL,
ROUND((E.SALDO5/P.SALDO5),2) AS MAYO,
ROUND((E.SALDO6/P.SALDO6),2) AS JUNIO,
ROUND((E.SALDO7/P.SALDO7),2) AS JULIO,
ROUND((E.SALDO8/P.SALDO8),2) AS AGOSTO,
ROUND((E.SALDO9/P.SALDO9),2) AS SEPTIEMBRE,
ROUND((E.SALDO10/P.SALDO10),2) AS OCTUBRE,
ROUND((E.SALDO11/P.SALDO11),2) AS NOVIEMBRE,
ROUND((E.SALDO12/P.SALDO12),2) AS DICIEMBRE

FROM SALDOSCC E, SALDOSCC P
WHERE ( (E.CODIGO_C = '1100000000000000' AND P.CODIGO_C = '2100000000000000') AND (LTRIM(STR(E.PERIODO,4)) = '2024' AND LTRIM(STR(P.PERIODO,4)) = '2024') )
)
SELECT Mes, Valor
FROM Ratios
UNPIVOT (
    Valor FOR Mes IN ([ENERO], [FEBRERO], [MARZO], [ABRIL], [MAYO], [JUNIO],[JULIO], [AGOSTO], [SEPTIEMBRE], [OCTUBRE], [NOVIEMBRE], [DICIEMBRE])
) AS Unpivoted;

--- RESULTADO ---

